# Ajax does not work when it is in a js page in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

Hi all I am having a problem when trying to split this code into a js file from the laravel page: php

In laravel page

```
    $(".importer").click(function(e) {
            // Stops the form from reloading


            var parent = $('#parentdoc').val();

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                }
            });
            let fichiers_upload = new FormData();
            let TotalFichiers = $('#fichiers-upload')[0].files.length; //Total Images
            let images = $('#fichiers-upload')[0];
            for (let i = 0; i < TotalFichiers; i++) {
                fichiers_upload.append('images' + i, images.files[i]);
            }
            fichiers_upload.append('TotalFichiers', TotalFichiers);
            fichiers_upload.append('idf', parent);
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{route('upload')}}",         
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: fichiers_upload,

                success: function(result) {
                    $('#fichiers-upload').val("");
                  
                }
            });
        });
```

This works fine in the laravel page but if I create a js page to separate it from the laravel page
doing

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('admin/import.js')}}">`

I get this error

````
exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"
file: "/home/vol1_3/epizy.com/epiz_27528825/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php"
line: 369
message: "CSRF token mismatch." ```
````

Comment: javascript goes in script tags, not `<link rel="stylesheet"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the tag is wrong.  This is for linking CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('admin/import.js')}}">
```

What you want is a script element:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('admin/import.js')}}"></script>
```

(I'm honestly surprised that even worked for you *at all*.)

More to the point of the error though, the literal string `"{{ csrf_token() }}"` is not the CSRF token.  This is a placeholder which the server-side framework will replace with an actual value when rendering the page.  But it doesn't do this for `.js` resources.

One approach could be to add that value to the page itself, perhaps somewhere in the `<head>` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
</script>
```

As long as it's added before any other `.js` files are loaded, the window-level constant `csrf_token` would then be available to any of the other JavaScript code.  Which you'd use in your AJAX:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf_token
    }
});
```

Alternatively, if you want you can just put the call to `$.ajaxSetup` itself in the page, after loading jQuery but before any of your AJAX calls, and then it can directly make use of the CSRF token placeholder.  Either way works, it's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Use Script tag instead of link tag to include your JS file:

```
<script src="{{ asset('admin/import.js')}}"></script>
```

Link tag is used to attach CSS files.

Comment: @selfself, it happen to all of us

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the token name to _token

```
headers: {
   '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('admin/import.js')}}">
```

to :

```
<script src="{{ asset('admin/import.js')}}"></script>
```